# how to remove right click menu in swf (flash cs4 using action script 3 ,flash 9)?

Tags: apache-flex, animation, air, flash

i made swf using flash 9 player if i right click swf it will shows menu like  zoom in , zoom out, etc option . how to remove right click menu in swf .

Answer (score 2):

check this post: http://blog.another-d-mention.ro/programming/right-click-and-custom-context-menu-in-flash-flex/. If you don't want any interaction with the right click, you can just use that javascript so you add a layer on top of your flash that catches the right click events and stops them from getting to the flash player.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this method](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/ui/ContextMenu.html#hideBuiltInItems()), or read in [this class](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/ui/ContextMenu.html) about what else you can do with the context menu.

Comment: i can't  import any package . becuase i used time line animation . any other possiable way for remove right click menu

Comment: You can use import statements in timeline code, and you generally don't have to either. I gave you the docs, now read them! ;)

Answer (score 0):

i saw ur refer url it's shows Redraw Regions option only .you will changed on your embed code

Comment: i added menu="false" in embed code . but not use . it shows all option . what can i do ?

Answer (score 0):

The as3 (in movie) put this in first frame :):

```
myMenu.hideBuiltInItems();
_root.menu = myMenu;
```

In html:

```
<EMBED src=Yourswf.swf type="text/html;  
charset=iso-8859-1" quality="high" menu=false  
bgcolor=#000000 WIDTH=120 HEIGHT=30>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<param name="MENU" value="false">
```